# Remove existing class

Tags: alpine.js

Let's say I have this HTML element with an Alpine.js class binding:

```html
<li id="123" 
    :class="$el.id === activeId ? 'bg-pink-900 text-white' : 'bg-gray-100'">Foo</li>
```

This works fine as long as my server rendered HTML doesn't look like this:

```html
<li id="123"
    class="bg-pink-900 text-white"
    :class="$el.id === activeId ? 'bg-pink-900 text-white' : 'bg-gray-100'">Foo</li>
```

Now, when `activeId` doesn't match, `bg-pink-900 text-white` isn't removed from the element which has been rendered server side at first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attribute *:class* in AlpineJs has a special behavior: it preserves the existing classes on an element.
The reason is because there are generally classes that you want to keep regardless of the condition.

The solution is to remove the 'static' class assignement:

```html
<li id="123"
    :class="$el.id === activeId ? 'bg-pink-900 text-white' : 'bg-gray-100'"
>
    Foo
</li>
```

[Here](https://alpinejs.dev/directives/bind#special-behavior) the explanation of this behavior

You may also take a look to the [Class object syntax](https://alpinejs.dev/directives/bind#class-object-syntax):

```html
<li id="123"
    :class="{'bg-pink-900 text-white': $el.id === activeId,
             'bg-gray-100': $el.id !== activeId
            }"
>
    Foo
</li>
```

Comment: In fact, I have already tried the suggested approach because I read about the preserving behavior. It works, but has the disadvantage that Alpine must first be loaded for the classes to be assigned. I just wanted to double check I didn't miss another option. Thanks!